# Deja vu reading question about Engineer turned manager training their subordinates for the next job

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

I just read the question [Dealing with manager that has high turnover but great reviews from departing engineers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/186705/dealing-with-manager-that-has-high-turnover-but-great-reviews-from-departing-eng).

Didn't we have the same exact question on the site before? I feel like I already read this in multiple variations, always by throwaway accounts (1 rep, no other sites visited).

Edit 2022/10/6:

Next one: [Manager hogging promotions/requisitions by overtraining subordinates](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/187771/manager-hogging-promotions-requisitions-by-overtraining-subordinates)

I could not find any of the duplicates. Am I seeing things that don't exist?

Comment: It looks similar to [Insubordinate chief engineer training colleagues to be "too mobile" out of spite](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/166883/insubordinate-chief-engineer-training-colleagues-to-be-too-mobile-out-of-spite), but I think I've seen others as well in the past (I know you've seen this comment on the actual question, but just posting it here for completeness).

Comment: MBAs can't handle the truth, hence the throwaways and lack of accepted answers.

Comment: @IanKemp that or trolls making up posts...

Comment: Maybe naïveté on my part, but *why* would someone invest time and energy into astroturfing the same (core) question over and over? What do they gain from it?

Comment: @esqew I don't know. For a while we had a person who would ask variations of "I pooped in my bosses office" every few weeks. I guess they get something out of it. The only way to stop it is to not entertain them.

Answer (score 21):

No, you are not seeing things that don't exist. This is a common theme that appears a couple times a year: "We deceive and cheat our employees as a matter of policy. One of our most valuable workers has caught on to this and is rebelling. How can we force him to submit so we can continue to deceive and cheat him?"

- [How can I deal with troublesome Professional Engineer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63205/how-can-i-deal-with-troublesome-professional-engineer?rq=1)
- [Engineer refusing to file/disclose patents](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/132387/engineer-refusing-to-file-disclose-patents?rq=1)
- [Disciplining hard-working but insubordinate engineer or his superior?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/141781/disciplining-hard-working-but-insubordinate-engineer-or-his-superior?rq=1)
- [How to discipline overeager engineer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/145709/how-to-discipline-overeager-engineer?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How to force disgruntled worker not to publicly disclose "GPL'ed code"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/147134/how-to-force-disgruntled-worker-not-to-publicly-disclose-gpled-code?rq=1)
- [Refusing to increment productivity beyond salary raise](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/159902/refusing-to-increment-productivity-beyond-salary-raise?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Employee demanding company to guarantee counter-offer isn't his last promotion at this company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/163705/employee-demanding-company-to-guarantee-counter-offer-isnt-his-last-promotion-a?rq=1)
- [Departing senior engineer refuses to introduce replacement to open source community/peers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/166317/departing-senior-engineer-refuses-to-introduce-replacement-to-open-source-commun)
- [Insubordinate chief engineer training colleagues to be "too mobile" out of spite](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/166883/insubordinate-chief-engineer-training-colleagues-to-be-too-mobile-out-of-spite?rq=1)
- [Senior engineer suddenly unwilling to do extra work they used to do after being denied promotion](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/168661/senior-engineer-suddenly-unwilling-to-do-extra-work-they-used-to-do-after-being?rq=1)
- [Former employee indirectly poaching engineering talent](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/180422/former-employee-indirectly-poaching-engineering-talent?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Retaining ambitious employee with rare skill set](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183493/retaining-ambitious-employee-with-rare-skill-set)

Some are from the employees viewpoint:

- [Company banned references, senior engineer subverting ban; should I go along with free "workaround"?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/164194/company-banned-references-senior-engineer-subverting-ban-should-i-go-along-wit?rq=1)
- [Polite way to ask if senior management will screw me over?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/172530/polite-way-to-ask-if-senior-management-will-screw-me-over?rq=1)

Common elements in many of these questions:

- We have allowed the employee to become irreplaceable.
- We have violated the law and this rebellion is going to expose us to prosecution or lawsuit.
- The employee is responding to our actual policies instead of to the lies in our employee handbook.
- The employee has pointed out our hypocrisy to others which is encouraging them to also rebel.
- I don't have the power or authority to solve this, but my head is on the chopping block if I don't.
- The employee has told me exactly what he wants, but upper management has long-standing policies in place that block the solution.

Sadly, but not surprisingly, these questions all remain open. The solution is always obvious but it is never accepted.

Comment: Appreciate the summary! If you see questions like this in future, by all means flag them for moderator attention. These types of questions in particular are difficult to judge. Most of the questions that end up popular tend to follow this kind of pattern. One of the most telling signs is usually that the OP puts in place bizarre constrains that mean there just aren't any good answers. That also makes the post unsuitable for Q&A purposes so these tend to be easier for us to handle.